# Speed up structured NumPy array

Tags: performance, python-3.x, numpy

`NumPy` arrays are great for both performance and easy use (easier slicing, indexing than lists).

I try to construct a data container out of a `NumPy structured array` instead of `dict` of `NumPy arrays`. The problem is the performance is much worse. About 2.5 times as bad using homogeneous data and about 32 times for heterogeneous data (I'm talking about `NumPy` datatypes).

Is there a way to speed the structured array's up? I tried changing the memoryorder from 'c' to 'f' but this didn't have any affect.

Here's my profiling code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

NP_SIZE = 100000
N_REP = 100

np_homo = np.zeros(NP_SIZE, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.double)], order='c')
np_hetro = np.zeros(NP_SIZE, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.int32)], order='c')
dict_homo = {'a': np.zeros(NP_SIZE), 'b': np.zeros(NP_SIZE)}
dict_hetro = {'a': np.zeros(NP_SIZE), 'b': np.zeros(NP_SIZE, np.int32)}

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(N_REP):
    np_homo['a'] += i

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(N_REP):
    np_hetro['a'] += i

t2 = time.time()
for i in range(N_REP):
    dict_homo['a'] += i

t3 = time.time()
for i in range(N_REP):
    dict_hetro['a'] += i
t4 = time.time()

print('Homogeneous Numpy struct array took {:.4f}s'.format(t1 - t0))
print('Hetoregeneous Numpy struct array took {:.4f}s'.format(t2 - t1))
print('Homogeneous Dict of numpy arrays took {:.4f}s'.format(t3 - t2))
print('Hetoregeneous Dict of numpy arrays took {:.4f}s'.format(t4 - t3))
```

**Edit**: Forgot to put my timing numbers:

```
Homogenious Numpy struct array took 0.0101s
Hetoregenious Numpy struct array took 0.1367s
Homogenious Dict of numpy arrays took 0.0042s
Hetoregenious Dict of numpy arrays took 0.0042s
```

**Edit2**: I added some additional test case with the timit module:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

NP_SIZE = 1000000

def time(data, txt, n_rep=1000):
    def intern():
        data['a'] += 1

    time = timeit.timeit(intern, number=n_rep)
    print('{} {:.4f}'.format(txt, time))


np_homo = np.zeros(NP_SIZE, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.double)], order='c')
np_hetro = np.zeros(NP_SIZE, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.int32)], order='c')
dict_homo = {'a': np.zeros(NP_SIZE), 'b': np.zeros(NP_SIZE)}
dict_hetro = {'a': np.zeros(NP_SIZE), 'b': np.zeros(NP_SIZE, np.int32)}

time(np_homo, 'Homogeneous Numpy struct array')
time(np_hetro, 'Hetoregeneous Numpy struct array')
time(dict_homo, 'Homogeneous Dict of numpy arrays')
time(dict_hetro, 'Hetoregeneous Dict of numpy arrays')
```

results in:

```
Homogeneous Numpy struct array 0.7989
Hetoregeneous Numpy struct array 13.5253
Homogeneous Dict of numpy arrays 0.3750
Hetoregeneous Dict of numpy arrays 0.3744
```

The ratios between the runs seem reasonably stable. Using both methods and a different size of the array.

For the offcase it matters:
python: 3.4
NumPy: 1.9.2

Comment: Since this question asks about a specific performance issue with NumPy rather than for a general critique, it has been migrated from Code Review to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you really want to work with structured arrays, I would suggest giving a try to [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6467

Comment: I see the same timings here. As for `np_homo` vs. `np_hetero`, maybe it has to do with alignment, because `np.int64` as the second dtype isn't so slow.

Comment: @MaxNoe. I saw it before I opened this question. I believe however that this is not the same thing since I use 1.9.2 and the problem freshly appeared in 1.10

Comment: Issue 6467 is a comparison between different `numpy` versions, not between NumPy structured arrays and python dictionaries. I, too, have similar timings here. And no satisfactory answers yet.

Answer (score 3):

In my quick timing tests the difference isn't that large:

```
In [717]: dict_homo = {'a': np.zeros(10000), 'b': np.zeros(10000)}
In [718]: timeit dict_homo['a']+=1
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.9 µs per loop
In [719]: np_homo = np.zeros(10000, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.double)])
In [720]: timeit np_homo['a'] += 1
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.3 µs per loop
```

In the `dict_homo` case, the fact that the array is embedded in a dictionary is a minor point.  Simple dictionary access like this is fast, basically the same as accessing the array by variable name.

So the first case it basically a test of `+=` for a 1d array.

In the structured case, the `a` and `b` values alternate in the data buffer, so `np_homo['a']` is a view that 'pulls out' alternative numbers.  So it's not surprising that it would be a bit slower.

```
In [721]: np_homo
Out[721]: 
array([(41111.0, 0.0), (41111.0, 0.0), (41111.0, 0.0), ..., (41111.0, 0.0),
       (41111.0, 0.0), (41111.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

A 2d array also interleaves the column values.

```
In [722]: np_twod=np.zeros((10000,2), np.double)
In [723]: timeit np_twod[:,0]+=1
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.8 µs per loop
```

Surprisingly it's actually a bit slower than the structured case.  Using `order='F'` or (2,10000) shape speeds it up a bit, but still not quite as good as the structured case.

These are small test times, so I won't make grand claims.  But the structured array doesn't look back.

---

Another time tests, initializing the array or dictionary fresh each step

```
In [730]: %%timeit np.twod=np.zeros((10000,2), np.double)
np.twod[:,0] += 1
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.7 µs per loop
In [731]: %%timeit np_homo = np.zeros(10000, dtype=[('a', np.double), ('b', np.double)])
np_homo['a'] += 1
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
In [732]: %%timeit dict_homo = {'a': np.zeros(10000), 'b': np.zeros(10000)}
dict_homo['a'] += 1
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 µs per loop
```

2d and structured are closer, with somewhat better performance for the dictionary (1d) case.  I tried this with `np.ones` as well, since `np.zeros` can have delayed allocation, but no difference in behavior.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. Especially the first results. Did you try to increasing the size of the elements? Just to be sure that the needed time is not dominated by some constant.