# What are the pros and cons of using a structured array in Numpy instead of several arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use Numpy to gather objects with the same properties in a efficient way. I don't know what to choose between using one [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) or several arrays.

For example, let's consider an object `Item` and its properties `id` (4 byte unsigned integer), `name` (20 unicode characters), `price` (4 byte float).

Using a structured array:

```
import numpy as np
item_dtype = np.dtype([('id', 'u4'), ('name', 'U20'), ('price', 'f4')])

# Populate:
raw_items = [(12, 'Bike', 180.54), (33, 'Helmet', 46.99)]
my_items_a = np.array(raw_items, dtype=item_dtype)

# Access:
my_items_a[0] # first item
my_items_a['price'][1] # price of second item
```

Using several arrays, wrapped in a class for convience:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, raw_items):
       n = len(raw_items)

       id, name, price = zip(*raw_items)

       self.id = np.array(id, dtype='u4')
       self.name = np.array(name, dtype='U20')
       self.price = np.array(price, dtype='f4')

# Populate:
my_items_b = Items(raw_items)

# Access:
(my_items_b.id[0], my_items_b.name[0], my_items_b.price[0]) # first item
my_items_b.price[1] # price of second item
```

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches? When using one instead of the other? Thanks

Comment: Some time tests: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34933105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one consideration is that of [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

In general, it's a good idea to structure the memory layout so that when you access some memory location, there's a good chance you'll access locations right near by. This will increase cache performance.

Consequently, regardless of the logical meaning of the data:

- If you have many operations where you will calculate something over all the fields of one record, then all the fields of the next record, etc., then you might consider  records.
- If you have many operations where you will calculate something over a single field for all entries, then something else for a different field for all entries, etc., then you might consider several arrays.

Asides from this, there's also the question of code clarity and ease of maintenance, so it's not a hard and fast rule. Also, in general, YMMV, so you should profile and instrument different options.